# How to initialize array of objects with user defined values and take input from user?

Tags: c++, class, constructor

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class car{

string owner;
string car_num;
string issue_date;

car(string o, string cn, string id)
{
    owner = o;
    car_num  = cn;
    issue_date = id;
}

void getInfo()
{
    cout << "Car's Owner's Name : " << owner << endl;
    cout << "Cars' Number : " << car_num << endl;
    cout << "Car's Issue Date : " << issue_date << endl;
}

};

int main()
{
    
    int n;
    cout << "Enter total number of cars stored in your garage : \n";
    cin >> n;
    car c1[n]; //incomplete code due to the issue


    return 0;
}
```

Here I want to take the total car numbers from user. And also want to take the car properties from user by using a loop. But how Can I do that while using a constructor?

Comment: Use `std::vector<car> cars;` instead of invalid car `c1[n];`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> car c1[n]; //incomplete code due to the issue

In fact, you have 2 issues here:

1. Variable-Length Arrays (VLA) are not allowed in standard C++. They
   are optionally allowed in standard C, and are supported by some
   C++ compilers as an extension.
2. You can't have an array of objects w/o default constructor (unless you fully initialize it).

Assuming you don't want to change the class (other than insert `public:` after the data members), the modern solution should use `std::vector`:

```
    std::vector<car> c;

    //incomplete part
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        std::string owner, car_num, issue_date;
        //TODO: get the strings from the user here ...
        c.emplace_back(owner, car_num, issue_date);
        }
```

Comment: @rifatibn just noticed and fixed important typo in the source code. No assignment was needed!

Answer (score 1):

My advice is not to over use the constructor. It supposed to construct, and really should only construct. In your case, you don't even really need a constructor.
Instead add a new function to do initialization.
Traditional is to use an [operator >>](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/overloading-operators-using-member-functions/) which is often an external function.
As for the loop...

> car c1[n]; //incomplete code due to the issue

is not legal C++ (although it's allowed in C, and many compilers that are also C compilers)
It's better to use a vector. So...

```
    vector<car> c1(n);
    for (auto& c : c1) 
       cin >> c;
```

An advanced technique is to use a [istream iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator), which will allow you to use algorithms like std::copy, calling the input operator for each member of the vector. However, it's really not required, just a "nicety"

Answer (score 0):

Use pointer array instead.e.g.

```
car* c1[n];

//incomplete part
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    //take input and process
    c1[i] = new car(//put processed inputs here);
    }
```

PS: I feel like I made a mistake somewhere but can't test it now. If it doesn't work, put a comment here.

Comment: Your solution is okay, a little old-school, but reasonable. However, the array is a VLA, and so not valid C++. It will work on many compilers, but it's not compliant code.

Comment: This is the easy version. Personally, I would prefer to put them in a linked list.

Comment: If you are looking for easy, I'd use a unique_ptr, your code also leaks :-)
Still, old-school code was often like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use loop with std::cin, like`for(int i=0;i<n;++i){std::cin<<num;}`. The 'n' I mentioned in the code can also be assigned by std::cin

```
int n;
std::cin>>n;
car* cars=new car[n];
for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
{
   std::getline(cars[i].owner,std::cin);
   // and something other you'd like to do, like to test its validity
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure your answer helps. I'm not sure why getline would help? (Maybe I'm missing something)?

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class car{
public:
string owner;
string car_num;
string issue_date;

void cars(string o, string cn, string id)
{
    owner = o;
    car_num  = cn;
    issue_date = id;
    getInfo();
}

void getInfo()
{
    cout << "Car's Owner's Name : " << owner << endl;
    cout << "Cars' Number : " << car_num << endl;
    cout << "Car's Issue Date : " << issue_date << endl;
}

};

int main()
{
    
    int n;
    string a,b,c;
    cout << "Enter total number of cars stored in your garage : \n";
    cin >> n;
    car cas[n]; //incomplete code due to the issue
    for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
    {
     cout<<"value1:";
     cin>>a;
     cout<<"value2:";
     cin>>b;
     cout<<"value3:";
     cin>>c;
     cas[i].cars(a,b,c);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem of an array of objects w/o default ctor. Also, `cas[i].cars(a,b,c);` is nonsense.